# Unable to convert a char pointer to integer

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion, memcpy

I am having a function to which char pointer is passed as an input. When I take the input passed by char pointer to an unsigned char it works fine. But, unsigned char is 1 byte long so I could take only those values which are one byte long. But,now I have to take the input which is 4 bytes long into a variable.

**My function is:**

```
void charPointer (char* aBinary)
{
    unsigned char aByte = '\0';

    memcpy(&aByte, &(aBinary[0]), 1);

    m1 = static_cast<short>(aSingleByte);
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Using `memcpy` here is completely unnecessary.  You are only overwriting a single character, just do `aBinaryIPAddress[0] = '\0';`.

Comment: `int mIPv4_1 = (int)aSingleByte;`  you even don't have to cast. why you are using `memcpy` to copy single byte?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple enough

```
unsigned char fourBytes[4];
memcpy(fourBytes, aBinaryIPAddress, 4);
```

Comment: It is giving me an error: error: invalid conversion from `unsigned char*' to `int'

Comment: Please have a look at the EDIT

Comment: better to use `hton()` if the endianity is unknown

Comment: @SHR No it is not known

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can try the following.

```
int abc = *((const int *)fourBytes);
```

However, if the byte order of `fourBytes` are different, then you need to manually copy each bytes into integer as shown in the following way.

```
int addr;
addr = 0;
addr = aBinaryIPAddress[0];
addr = (addr << 8)|aBinaryIPAddress[1];
addr = (addr << 8)|aBinaryIPAddress[2];
addr = (addr << 8)|aBinaryIPAddress[3];
```

You can also do it in the following way

```
int addr;
memcpy(&addr, aBinaryIPAddress, numbytes); //numbytes = 4
```

Please note that `short` is 2 bytes long.

Comment: It is giving me an error: error: invalid conversion from unsigned char*' to int'

Comment: Please have a look at the EDIT

Comment: @Prats: Please look into the edited answer. I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this sample:
The 'f' function take 4 bytes from buffer and return them as int.

The cout result will be 4030201 on little endian,

On big endian machine it will be 1020304.

```
#include <iostream>

int f(char* buff)
{
    int &n=*(int*)buff;
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    char buff[20]={1,2,3,4,5};

    std::cout<<std::hex<<f(buff)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the solution to be machine specific, please give me a solution which is not machine specific